# Error while parsing xml in Hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive

I am using Hive to parse xml files for that i am usinge **hivexmlserde**.
When i am writing my code and executing it i am getting below error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: The number of XPath expressions does not much the number of columns
```

but my column numbers and xpath expressions are same.

Below is my code:

```
add jar /home/cloudera/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE INFO(
statusCode string,
title string,
startTime string,
endTime string,
frequencyValue string,
frequencyUnits string,
strengthValue string,
strengthUnits string,
routecode string,
routecodeSystem string,
routedisplayName string,
routecodesystemName string,
ugcode string,
uname string,
ucodeSystem string,
codeSystemName string,
ageForm string,
tr_code string,
tr_description string,
tr_codesystem string,
tr_codesystemname string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.statusCode"="Document/xxx/statusCode/text()",
"column.xpath.title"="Document/xxx/code/code/text()",
"column.xpath.startTime"="Document/xxx/startTime/text()",
"column.xpath.endTime"="Document/xxx/endTime/text()",
"column.xpath.frequencyValue"="Document/xxx/frequencyValue/text()",
"column.xpath.frequencyUnits"="Document/xxx/frequencyUnits/text()",
"column.xpath.strengthValue"="Document/xxx/strengthValue/text()",
"column.xpath.strengthUnits"="Document/xxx/strengthUnits/text()",
"column.xpath.routecode"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/routeCode/code/text()",
"column.xpath.routecodeSystem"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/routeCode/codeSystem/text()",
"column.xpath.routedisplayName"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/routeCode/displayName/text()",
"column.xpath.routecodesystemName"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/routeCode/codeSystemName/text()",
"column.xpath.ugcode"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/code/text()",
"column.xpath.ugname"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/displayName/text()",
"column.xpath.ugcodeSystem"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/codeSystem/text()",
"column.xpath.ugcodeSystemName"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/codeSystemName/text()",
"column.xpath.dosageForm"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/ageForm/displayName/text()",
"column.xpath.tr_code"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/translation/code/text()",
"column.xpath.tr_description"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/translation/displayName/text()",
"column.xpath.tr_codesystem"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/translation/codeSystem/text()",
"column.xpath.tr_codesystem"="Document/xxx/entryInfo/productCode/translation/codeSystemName/text()"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<Document",
"xmlinput.end"="</Document>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue after a bit of code digging. I was facing that issue because 2 xpath column names i made same.

> column.xpath.tr_codesystem

was repeated twice in the SERDEPROPERTIES. I changed it to **codesystemname** than it started working for me.